# QxtLogger (From libQxt) prints its Messages in Application Output

Tags: qt, logging, signals-slots, qt4.8, libqxt

I am using QxtLogger (from libQxt) for logging in our application. It was working fine with Qt 4.7.3.

I recently **updated to Qt 4.8**, Since then log messages from QxtLogger are getting printed in Application Output.
I didn't installed it as QtMessageHandler, I am not able to point out exact cause.

Any pointer or solution will be very helpful..